# Rails 3 - basic http authentication vs authentication token with iphone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, devise

Initially I was using basic http authentication to authenticate a user with devise following this guide:

http://jessehowarth.com/2011/04/27/ajax-login-with-devise

I was successfully able to authenticate a user, but the session remained logged in forever. There was no way to destroy the user's session. In fact, when I added the user_signed_in? method of devise within my create method, it would always return true even when logging out via json. So I came to conclusion that there is no way to end a session using basic http authentication. All you could really do is check if the user is already signed in and send a status code as json back to the client.

So then I tried the authentication token route, which allowed you to create a session with an authentication token and then destroy a session by deleting that authentication token, and the user would have to sign in again in order to access pages that require authentication, as shown in this post:

[Devise and Authentication with CURL !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400017/devise-and-authentication-with-curl)

The downside of this is the fact that you have this very long string that you have to enter in for each page that requires authentication, which seems a little undesirable. I wish there was a best of both worlds here, where you can log in and out like you do in a web browser.

Im not sure if everything I am saying is accurate, but it seems in line with this post:

[http authentication in devise and rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449852/http-authentication-in-devise-and-rails-3)

In that post, he says authentication token is "more secure than http basic authentication since the key can expire". I assume he means that once you are logged in using basic authentication, then that's it, you are logged in forever, whereas authentication token you can expire it and force the user to sign in again. Is this accurate interpretation?

Thanks for response

Comment: I noticed you set the HTTP method to POST and set the X-HTTP-Method-Override header instead of setting the HTTP method to DELETE. Have you tried 
`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' 
-X DELETE \
 http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out \
-d '{"remote": "true", "commit": "Sign Out", "utf8": "✓", "user": {"remember_me": "1", "password": "password", "email": "email@email.com"}}' \
-c cookie` ?

Comment: I reformatted question, so now it's just a yes or no question. Still no response though.

Answer (score 0):

The way that HTTP authentication works, once a browser is logged in (i.e. is sending `WWW-Authenticate` headers), it will stay logged in until its HTTP authentication cache is expired (usually when you exit the browser).

Since browsers continue to send valid credentials in HTTP authentication (there is no "HTTP logout"), that's why you're seeing the user still logged in.

My recommendation is to use the `authentication_token` functionality in Devise and pass `?auth_token` to your APIs. Keep in mind that you have to pass them as part of the URL even if it is a POST/DELETE/PUT/etc. (this is a Devise bug that may be fixed by now).